# Automating "Complete Certificate Request" in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, x509certificate

I'm using .NET and X509Certificate2 trying to automate importing a .cer file containing a certificate where the request was made separately on the server. The .cer file can be manually imported via the IIS "Complete Certificate Request" dialog and it correctly picks up the associated private key. However doing an Import of the .cer and adding it to the certificate store fails to pick up the private key.

```
byte [] certBytes = "xxxxx"; // CER file converted to bytes
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2();
cert.Import(certBytes);

X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
if (store.Certificates.Contains(cert)) {
    store.Remove(cert);
}
store.Add(cert);
store.Close();
```

Is there something extra I need to be doing to imitate the process done with "Complete Certificate Request" in IIS?

Comment: There is no .NET BCL classes for that purpose, so you have to use the command line or COM object, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/certreq_1#certreq--accept

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IX509Enrollment` COM interface and its [`InstallResponse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/certenroll/nf-certenroll-ix509enrollment-installresponse) method to automate enrollment completion process. Note that you must call a [`IX509Enrollment::Initialize(X509CertificateEnrollmentContext)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/certenroll/nf-certenroll-ix509enrollment-initialize) method to select the context. Reference the `CertEnroll.dll` COM library in your project to access these interfaces.